# how to capture braintree using customer token in magento2

Tags: magento2, token, braintree

I enabled vault feature in Braintree.In frontend by default customer should store their credit card(force fully) at checkout.

For example, the customer places an order value with $100.

Now I captured amount by generating an invoice with capture online.

Now I want to capture $15 extra amount using customer Token.
Can you help me how to do programmatically?
Below code using txn_id but I need capture through the token.

Client will share order increment Id, Extra Amount to Capture in CSV file.
So using Order Increment Id I can get order id, order payment id.

1.how to get token associated to payment id?

2.How to charge extra amount using that token?

```
 \Magento\Braintree\Model\Adapter\BraintreeAdapter $brainTreeAdapter
    $result = $this->brainTreeAdapter->submitForSettlement($txnId, $amount);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento provides `API` to work with payment tokens. The [PaymentTokenManagementInterface](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Vault/Api/PaymentTokenManagementInterface.php) contains a list of methods to retrieve tokens:

- getListByCustomerId
- getByPaymentId
- getByGatewayToken
- getByPublicHash

The stored token can be used for to perform payment operations (see [Braintree sale](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/transaction/sale/php#payment_method_token)):

```
\Braintree\Transaction::sale([
    'paymentMethodToken' => 'your gateway token',
    'amount' => 'your amount'
]);
```

Magento already has implemented [the adapter](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Braintree/Model/Adapter/BraintreeAdapter.php) to communicate with Braintree and as an example, you can look how to implemented partial invoicing in Magento Braintree payment module. The [BraintreeVaultCaptureCommand](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Braintree/etc/di.xml#L133) uses [VaultCaptureDataBuilder.php](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Braintree/Gateway/Request/VaultCaptureDataBuilder.php#L46) to set payment gateway token for a sale request.

About your second question. You can perform partial invoicing only for a previously authorized amount and according to your example:

- Customer places the order with $100.
- You create an invoice in admin panel with $85 amount.
- You can create another invoice with $15 amount.

You can't capture extra $15 amount if your first invoice was with $100 amount. Braintree [does not allow](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/transaction/submit-for-settlement/php#arg.amount) to capture more amount than was authorized. So, if your extra capture more than authorized amount, you need to perform new authorization transaction with saved payment token.

Comment: Yes,I want create new transaction for extra $15 capture.in this new transaction auth&capture. i mean i want direct capture.